# iOS: tabBarItems on top of each other

Tags: ios

I am making a browser inside of a web.

At the buttom of the view, there's a toolbar where there are the buttons, back, forward and UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh.

However, when you click on refresh, it should be replaced with UIBarButtonSystemItemStop.

When the page finishes loading, the stop button will be replaced by refresh.

Instead of removing/adding the buttons (which I dont know how to do), I want to use the setHidden method instead.

Is there a way to put the refresh and stop on top of each other in interface builder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to create images of the 2 system items.

Create linkage with xcode.

Then call setImage on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to put one button bar item on top of another in interface builder, but you can think of changing the item's icon programmatically.

I see two possibilities:

- you can use the `– setItems:animated:` selector of your `UIToolbar` to define the new set of `UIBarItem`'s (which is exactly the original one minus the button you want to remove, plus the one you want to make appear);
- you can keep pointers to the `UIBarItem/UIBarButtonItem`s that you want to modify and set their image property when appropriate.

Comment: Yes but how?
the only way it works is     [[[toolBar subviews] objectAtIndex:2 ] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"left_arrow.png"]]; but something weird happens.

Comment: what you are doing is directly accessing the subviews of the `UIToolbar`, not changing the corresponding `UIBarItem/UIBarButtonItem`. See my edit for your last question.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simply changing the UIBarButton enumerated type change the image for you?